# How can I reduce hi-fi amplifier latency?

Tags: mixer, music, amplifier, behringer

I've currently got a semi-home-studio cobbled together using bits and pieces that I had lying around.  I've noticed that when I play my instrument through speakers, there's noticeable latency, about 40ms.  When I listen through headphones directly from the mixer, there's no noticeable latency.

The setup is like this:

Instrument(s) -> Behringer Q802USB mixer -> Pioneer XC-HM51 mini hi-fi -> Speakers

Headphones at either the instrument output or mixer output has minimal latency, but headphones at the hi-fi output (or speakers) has latency which makes me suspect the Hi-Fi.  Do I need to find a different hi-fi system, or use a dedicated amplifier?

FYI, I measured the latency by having a microphone between my electronic snare drum and the speaker, and measuring the time between the sound from hitting the snare, and the sound coming out of the speaker.  From one hit, there's two peaks about 40ms apart.

Comment: How did you connect the mixer to the amplifier? If it's via USB, that's where the latency is introduced.

Comment: 1/4" to RCA cable

Answer (score 1):

If the input is analog but you still get a delay, it's likely the amplifier does an AD conversion on its inputs. In that case, you'd need to use a different amplifier you are certain is analog.

Comment: Cheers, that's what I suspected but wasn't sure if it was possible!  

Is there any way to tell whether an amplifier is analogue?  Is it usually a spec sheet, or "dedicated" amps (without any extra functions), or is it basically just a bit random?

Comment: The spec sheet or manual may tell you, but some don't. The manual for your amp doesn't specify if it's digital, for example. Signs an amplifier may be digital: USB ports, HDMI input, other digital inputs. Functions like time alignment.

Answer (score -1):

You are going to blow your stereo, dont do it, get a guitar amp

those speakers cant handle instruments (sounds rediculous but i've blown a couple and seen plenty of others).

if you wanna do it anyway, there should be a straight through mode (maybe not after looking at the book).

i'd try turning p.bass off and setting eq to flat, also treble and bass to 0. basically turn every effect off and try that. [Manual PDF pg 14](https://www.manua.ls/pioneer/xc-hm51/manual?p=14).

otherwise your outta luck. i doubt the mixer has noticable latency

Comment: anyone know why this was downvoted? ok setting the paramaters to 0 probably won't disable processing and it will still induce latency, but i did say 'try' it out and see.